# Wrapping C# C++

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli, wrapper

I would like to wrap a native library with C++/CLI. It's work with primitive type. But in the following case, it's more complicated :

```
interface ISampleInterface
{
    void SampleMethod();
}

public ref class NativeClassWrapper {
    NativeClass* m_nativeClass;

public:
    NativeClassWrapper() { m_nativeClass = new NativeClass(); }
    ~NativeClassWrapper() { delete m_nativeClass; }
    void Method(ISampleInterface ^i) {
        ???
        m_nativeClass->Method(i);
    }
};
```

How to wrap this ? Because the native code C++ doesn't know the ISampleInterface type... (Same question with a virtual class)

Thanks you.

Comment: Why does `NativeClass::Method` need access to `ISampleInterface`? As you noted, it *can't* use it, so you need a way to change the design.

Comment: The native code needs to access to a class which implements ISampleInterface. In this example, it's an interface, but it can be a class. The problem in this design is the native code doesn't know the type of the element manipulated by C++/CLI. I have no idea how to resolve this problem. Which does design use ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes in the code snippet.  Let's start with a clean example, declaring the native class first:

```
#pragma unmanaged
class INativeInterface {
public:
    virtual void SampleMethod() = 0;
};

class NativeClass {
public:
    void Method(INativeInterface* arg);
};
```

And the managed interface:

```
#pragma managed
public interface class IManagedInterface
{
    void SampleMethod();
};
```

So what you need is a native wrapper class that derives from INativeInterface so that you can pass an instance of it to NativeClass::Method().  All that this wrapper has to do is simply delegate the call to the corresponding managed interface method.  Usually a simple one-liner unless argument types need to be converted.  Like this:

```
#pragma managed
#include <msclr\gcroot.h>

class NativeInterfaceWrapper : public INativeInterface {
    msclr::gcroot<IManagedInterface^> itf;
public:
    NativeInterfaceWrapper(IManagedInterface^ arg) : itf(arg) {};
    virtual void SampleMethod() {
        itf->SampleMethod();
    }
};
```

Now your method implementation becomes easy:

```
void Method(IManagedInterface^ i) {
    NativeInterfaceWrapper wrap(i);
    m_nativeClass->Method(&wrap);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, it works fine. Do you know the equivalent of msclr::gcroot in JAVA ?

Comment: @user1886318: It looks like `jobject` is roughly equivalent to `GCHandle`, and you'd need to make your own RAII wrapper around that to make sure it automatically gets released when the native code no longer needs it.  Or borrow one, but I don't think there's an official JNI-sanctioned wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

If your native class needs to callback into .NET code, you need to use the `gcroot` template. Wuth this you can store the managed object in an unmanaged class. In this unmanaged class you can then use a native "callback" and then use the member stored in `gcroot´ to callback into managed code (ISampleInterface).

See also:

- [How to: Declare Handles in Native Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/481fa11f)
- [How to: Hold Object Reference in Native Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aeb4be4k)
- [Best Practices for Writing Efficient and Reliable Code with C++/CLI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730837)

Comment: Thanks you, indeed I have to use gcroot.